# Can I switch out .Net cache provider through configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, memcached, provider

**Is there a way in .Net to switch out the Cache provider just like I would a membership provider, or role provider? I would like to keep the code untouched but switch to using a distributed cache like memcached or AppFabric.**

All I am finding is how to switch out the output cache provider. This might be necessary, but it doesn't solve the issue of when Cache is called directly from within my code.

I've found many libraries and they abstract Cache behind an interface, but this would mean I have to go to every spot in my code and inject the new abstraction. Also I am using PLINQO, which internally uses Cache.

Is OutputCache the only thing I can switch out through configuration?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm starting to feel it might not be possible to do this, it seems like everyone and their mother has created a Cache abstraction... well except for Microsoft :).  http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks/plinqo/tour/caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/akrakovetsky/aspnet-40-cache-extensibility) which explains the pre-.NET 4.0 state of caching and what .NET 4.0 brings in this respect. In .NET 4.0 the caching has been completely reworked into a separate assembly ([System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx)) and rendered extensible. That's true for both object caching and page output caching. Unfortunately if you have current code that relies on the old `Cache` class this has to be changed as this class works with in-memory objects only.

Comment: Thanks this helps, but it is what I feared. That migrating will be an effort. Probably worth it though.